# why two numbers in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand why android uses two sets on numbers , platform version and API level. API Level, documentation states that "Each Android platform version supports exactly one API Level", does that mean, Google can provide a new(improved) platform, but still decides to go with earlier API level thus not making any change in Java API's for the developers in the new platform. Is my understanding correct? 
Also, what changes happen when platform version changes?

Comment: I think that is theoretically possible, yes, although in practice thus far each platform version has a different API level.  When you are writing code you are only concerned with the API level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to think API and platform are not interrelated.

Platform changes would most likely be performance improvements, improved security, or better framework.

Whereas API versions can be introductions of new or improved interfacing methods.